# Setting values in matrices - Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix, setting

I made i matrix  5x3

```
field = []
fields = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        for j in range(0,3):
            x = 1
            field.append(x)
    fields.append(field)
```

When i want to change one field

```
fields[2][2] = 0
```

i get this:

```
fields[0][0] = 1
fields[0][1] = 1
fields[0][2] = **0**
fields[1][0] = 1
fields[1][1] = 1
fields[1][2] = **0**
fields[2][0] = 1
fields[2][1] = 1
fields[2][2] = **0**
fields[3][0] = 1
fields[3][1] = 1
fields[3][2] = **0**
fields[4][0] = 1
fields[4][1] = 1
fields[4][2] = **0**
```

---

Instead one change i am getting five

Comment: I just want to change one field, i dont know why but on this way he always change 5 fields ( for fields[x][y] he is changing whole y column not xy value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have the reference to the same `field` across all rows.

You want this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    field = []
    for j in range(0,3):
        x = 1
        field.append(x)
    fields.append(field)
```

`field` should get reset for every row. That's why you should have it inside the first loop. Now your `fields[2][2] = 0` would work.

```
>>> fields
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> fields[2][2] = 0
>>> fields
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that each row of your list refers to the same object, the list named `field`. You can see this by looking at the `id` of each row. You will find that:

```
id(fields[0]) == id(fields[1])
id(fields[0]) == id(fields[2])
```

and so on. Each row is in fact the same object.

You need to create a separate list for each row:

```
fields = []
for i in range(0,5):
    field = []
    for j in range(0,3):
        x = 1
        field.append(x)
    fields.append(field)
```

And now you will see that:

```
id(fields[0]) != id(fields[1])
```

and so on. And your attempts to modify individual elements will behave as you intend.

But really, if you want to work with matrices, then you should use numpy.